# C# Wpf Web Browser Navigation Error: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, wpf

I am doing a custom project as a learning experience, I have a web browser inside a c# wpf project in vs2013, If I search for https:// www the search is successful, If i Search for www. the search has an error and if I just search without http or www. then also I get an error.

How can I bypass this and get successful search every time?

Will I have to make a small algorithm to detect the first few characters in the text box string for example if textbox contains https:// or www. or != then it automatically appends the front of the string with the required to search successfully or is there another way? (Eg implement google/yahoo searchbox?)

Thanks

Comment: Which browser? Is it the default wpf one? Or some third party control? Or are you creating your own browser?

Comment: How are you searching? Are you appending text to "https://www.google.co.in/q=" for example?

Comment: I'm just using the standard webBrowser.navigate(string);